# Best way to sum by group in R

Tags: r, dplyr

I'm looking for the best way to add totals to my dataframe by grouping using different strings.

I'm using the dplyr package, and am trying to group_by and then summarize but I can't work out how to bind the result to my data, and it seems to take a lot of computing power to get the result.  I must be doing something silly as sometimes it's causing my R to crash.

My input looks like this:

```
input = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 
3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AUD_report.csv", "EUR_report.csv", 
"USD_report.csv"), class = "factor"), V2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 
5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 
3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L), .Label = c("China", 
"Russia", "Russia+China", "Total", "USA"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 
    5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("AUD.Down", "AUD.Up", "EUR.Down", 
    "EUR.Up", "USD.Down", "USD.Up"), class = "factor"), V4 = c(48591.60454, 
    40676.28059, 11754.42972, 23105.87013, 34889.8494, 22707.7926, 
    -9797.863699, -24967.36796, -1948.341356, -46439.5565, -4696.825603, 
    112.4201527, -6685.354724, -8046.764957, -30556.83101, 2284.342847, 
    -450.8694417, 12271.82235, 4217.944692, 4122.821968, -15363.9665, 
    -9120.8843, -13710.22842, -23455.23046, 12266.60417, 14432.84508, 
    15825.67672, 41639.71043)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, 
-28L))
```

and I'm trying to get an output that looks like this:

```
output = structure(list(V1 = structure(c(1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
1L, 1L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 
4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L), .Label = c("AUD_report.csv", 
"EUR_report.csv", "TOT_report.csv", "USD_report.csv"), class = "factor"), 
    V2 = structure(c(2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 
    2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 5L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 
    1L, 3L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L, 2L, 1L, 3L, 5L, 4L), .Label = c("China", 
    "Russia", "Russia+China", "Total", "USA"), class = "factor"), 
    V3 = structure(c(2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 
    4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 8L, 7L, 
    7L, 7L, 7L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 6L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L, 5L), .Label = c("AUD.Down", 
    "AUD.Up", "EUR.Down", "EUR.Up", "TOT.Down", "TOT.Up", "USD.Down", 
    "USD.Up"), class = "factor"), V4 = c(48591.60454, 40676.28059, 
    11754.42972, 23105.87013, 34889.8494, 22707.7926, -9797.863699, 
    -24967.36796, -1948.341356, -46439.5565, -4696.825603, 112.4201527, 
    -6685.354724, -8046.764957, -30556.83101, 2284.342847, -450.8694417, 
    12271.82235, 4217.944692, 4122.821968, -15363.9665, -9120.8843, 
    -13710.22842, -23455.23046, 12266.60417, 14432.84508, 15825.67672, 
    41639.71043, 28530.81243, 31667.81644, 1348.876752, 5069.074998, 
    -19122.21206, 37258.73962, 4184.11194, 18095.28006, -12695.5456, 
    -677.0241094)), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -38L
))
```

I'm trying to sum the Ups and Downs for each group in V2, and have tried the mutate and summarise functions with little luck.  Could anyone point me in the right direction?

Answer (score 4):

```r
input %>% mutate(dir=str_split_fixed(V3,'\\.',2)[,2]) %>% 
  group_by(V2,dir) %>% summarise(V4=sum(V4)) %>% 
  mutate(V1='TOT_report.csv',V3=paste0('Total.',dir)) %>% select(-dir) %>% 
  bind_rows(input,.)

               V1           V2         V3          V4
1  AUD_report.csv       Russia     AUD.Up  48591.6045
2  AUD_report.csv        China     AUD.Up  40676.2806
3  AUD_report.csv          USA     AUD.Up  11754.4297
4  AUD_report.csv Russia+China     AUD.Up  23105.8701
5  AUD_report.csv        Total     AUD.Up  34889.8494
6  AUD_report.csv       Russia   AUD.Down  22707.7926
7  AUD_report.csv        China   AUD.Down  -9797.8637
8  AUD_report.csv          USA   AUD.Down -24967.3680
9  AUD_report.csv Russia+China   AUD.Down  -1948.3414
10 AUD_report.csv        Total   AUD.Down -46439.5565
11 EUR_report.csv       Russia     EUR.Up  -4696.8256
12 EUR_report.csv        China     EUR.Up    112.4202
13 EUR_report.csv          USA     EUR.Up  -6685.3547
14 EUR_report.csv Russia+China     EUR.Up  -8046.7650
15 EUR_report.csv        Total     EUR.Up -30556.8310
16 EUR_report.csv       Russia   EUR.Down   2284.3428
17 EUR_report.csv        China   EUR.Down   -450.8694
18 EUR_report.csv          USA   EUR.Down  12271.8224
19 EUR_report.csv Russia+China   EUR.Down   4217.9447
20 EUR_report.csv        Total   EUR.Down   4122.8220
21 USD_report.csv       Russia     USD.Up -15363.9665
22 USD_report.csv        China     USD.Up  -9120.8843
23 USD_report.csv Russia+China     USD.Up -13710.2284
24 USD_report.csv        Total     USD.Up -23455.2305
25 USD_report.csv       Russia   USD.Down  12266.6042
26 USD_report.csv        China   USD.Down  14432.8451
27 USD_report.csv Russia+China   USD.Down  15825.6767
28 USD_report.csv        Total   USD.Down  41639.7104
29 TOT_report.csv        China Total.Down   4184.1119
30 TOT_report.csv        China   Total.Up  31667.8164
31 TOT_report.csv       Russia Total.Down  37258.7396
32 TOT_report.csv       Russia   Total.Up  28530.8124
33 TOT_report.csv Russia+China Total.Down  18095.2801
34 TOT_report.csv Russia+China   Total.Up   1348.8768
35 TOT_report.csv        Total Total.Down   -677.0241
36 TOT_report.csv        Total   Total.Up -19122.2121
37 TOT_report.csv          USA Total.Down -12695.5456
38 TOT_report.csv          USA   Total.Up   5069.0750
```